# Conditional Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two conditions, they may be both set or just one of them. If both set to a value a linq where statement shall be triggered having AND as boolean operator else the linq where statement shall include only the filter based on the set condition.

For example:

both conditions set: linq.Where(condition1 && condition2)...

only condition1 set: linq.Where(condition1)..

only condition2 set: linq.Where(condition2)..

This is not allowed: linq.Where(condition1 || condition2) because the filtering shall be very accurate

Now my problem is how do I write ONE linq statement that considers all those requirements? Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Predicates might look like this: x => x > 10 or x => x == "Hello" or x => x + 2 == 3.. any expression that fits inside where statement.

I get the conditions/predicates, i do not create them myself

With predicates i mean those predicates in math and not the class in c#.

there is not much code to post since i do not know how to do this in ONE linq statement

The result has to be ONE linq statement handling all this.

I am new I do not know how to write this that why i was hoping you could help me out.

If you dont like it dont downvote it just pass on, somebody will help me out.

EDIT2:

I mean this. Not more, not less:

```
method<T> filterList(ienumerable<T> linq, Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2)
{
  return linq.Where(only p1 or only p2 or p1 && p2)
}
```

Comment: well just go witth your first statement and just make `condition1` always `true` if it is *not set* - if you give some real code I could even show you how

Comment: Just store the condition lambda in a variable and assign whichever function is relevant to it - then do `.Where(condition)`

Comment: I have to ask. Why? Why ONE linq statement? An if-else is too easy?

Comment: @CarstenKönig - Already realised that, removed my comment.. I also can't see why it needs to be linq, nor can I see the OP's own effort.

Comment: It seems the question is very open to interpretation and very unclear - let's put it on hold till the OP comes back and makes things more clear

Comment: @Steve its requirement, i know life is not easy

Comment: @devhedgehog please add some meaningful code and explain what you want to do a bit better - for example: are your conditions predicates? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: @CarstenKönig what is unclear? i work with predicates i get either one of them or two and if both set I should use AND operator inside linq. It hast to be one linq statement in the end.

Comment: @devhedgehog please just post a simple version as code - there is much unclear - for example how do your predicates look like? What kind of LINQ are you trying to use (for example if it needs to work with Linq2EF we cannot do as much as with Linq2Objects)

Comment: @CarstenKönig i edited my question. its linq to object.

Comment: ok - first your predicates all are about different types (`int`, `string`) - so this will be really difficult to get into *one* as the types just don't match. Second: reading this I get the feeling you are trying to implment some kind of solver - so are you looking for an `x`? What do you mean when you say you *get the conditions* - from where? In what format? What is your source you want the LINQ statements to act uppon?

Comment: also please take your time and give your question some formatting - having almost 4K rep and a gold badge, you should be able to do this by now

Comment: I edited my question again

Comment: @devhedgehog ok - now what is `method<T>`? and you don't give any list there - on top something like `linq.Where` makes no sense - in place of `linq` you need something like `myList.Where` (a `IEnumerable<T>` for example) - do you know your way around LINQ?

Comment: is all IEnumerable, filterList is just stupid name it could be filterblahblah :)

Comment: The more I look at this the more confused I get as to why you can't use `or`, if you drew a truth table that would be exactly what you have

Comment: no offense but I don't think @devhedgehog really knows how to use LINQ in the first place

Comment: That edit looks like pseudocode but it's close enough to real code that it makes guessing the intentions of the OP risky.

Comment: in my code, linq is the name of the IEnumerable<T> variable. The method accepts any IEnumerable<T> and two conditions of type Predicate<T>. The return result is IEnumerable<T>.Where(...). That is what I am looking for. Cant you see that in my pseudocode from above?

Comment: @devhedgehog Check my edited (again) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't say what to do if both are unset, I *assume* in this case no filtering at all
I *assume* by 'has no value' you mean for example p1 is null.
I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *ONE linq statement* but I would assume at least one of the below would meet your needs.

in all cases I'm saying basically [replace a null predicate with an always true predicate and and the predicates]

Solution 1

```
return linq.Where(x => p1 != null ? p1(x) : true).Where(x => p2 != null ? p2(x) : true);
```

Solution 2

```
var p1a = p1 ?? (x => true);
var p2a = p2 ?? (x => true);
return linq.Where(x => p1a(x) && p2a(x));
```

Solution 3

```
return linq.Where(x => (p1 ?? (y=>true))(x) && (p2 ?? (z=>true))(x));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the beauty of monads - you don't have to do everything in one step.

```
// bool? flag1
// bool? flag2
// IQueryable<something> collection


if(flag1.HasValue)
    collection = collection.Where(x => x.Flag1 == flag1);

if(flag2.HasValue)
    collection = collection.Where(x => x.Flag2 == flag2);

//...
```

Edit: if you want to do it in a single LINQ statement you'll need to do some trickery by invoking predicates:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FilterList<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2)
{
    return collection.Where(x =>
        (p1 == null || p1.Invoke(x)) &&
        (p2 == null || p2.Invoke(x))
    );
}
```

Comment: This is only able to perform an `and` operation, not `or`

Comment: this has nothing to do with IEnumerable beeing a monad ;)

Comment: @recursive what do you mean by "not `or`"?

Comment: @CarstenKönig:  At the end of the code, `collection` will contain all the items that matched all the filters.  The desired behavior is that `collection` should contain all the items that matched *any* of the filters.

Comment: @recursive it's not my code and if I read the OP correctly: "This is not allowed: linq.Where(condition1 || condition2) because the filtering shall be very accurate" he explicitly did not **want** this

Comment: I can see that interpretation now.  I assumed by "not allowed" he meant that he had not been able to achieve it yet, but now I doubt that reading.

Comment: @recursive I do not WANT condition1 || condition2

Comment: @CarstenKönig I disagree. While functional languages may provide more elegant ways to do conditional filtering, the fact that you can insert this type of code in the pipeline without affecting the code at either end seems very monadic.

Comment: @RaduPorumb maybe we should discuss this somewhere else (interested?) - just so much: the parts of LINQ having something to do with Monads are `SelectMany` and to some extent `Select` (the monadic bind and return)

Comment: @CarstenKönig sure, chat room?

Comment: @RaduPorumb sure if you know how to open one directly (I don't)

Comment: @devhedgehog Edited my answer with a single statement solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the third party [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), you can iteratively build `or` filters as well as `and`.

#### example

```
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
```

Comment: ok - while this now has some value (not only a link) it has no connection to the question - of course there can be none (because the question is very poor)

Comment: @CarstenKönig:  The question is asking how to create a single predicate that can be used by `Where` that's composed of two other predicates combined by `or`.  In my opinion, my answer is more relevant than any other answer currently posted for this question, since it shows a way to do that.

Comment: Upon closer reading, the question is definitely open to interpretation.  I might have misinterpreted.  Or maybe not.  Anyway, I'll leave this up in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: TBH: I cannot interpret the question at all - and I still think he does not want **or** at all ("both conditions set: linq.Where(condition1 && condition2)") - the rest is subjective

Comment: too complicated, i need one liner linq.

Comment: @devhedgehog why do you need a 1-liner? Is this homework? If so please post thre real question

Comment: @CarstenKönig sorry my english is bad, i need one linq statement.